# Extract Array of Strings from Decoded JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, key-value, jsondecoder

I am using JSONDecoder to decode JSON obtained from an API into an array of objects each of which contains a key value pair of interest. For that key, I would like to obtain an array of the values (that are strings). The JSON decodes fine into an array, however, I cannot extract an array of values for the key I'm interested in using Array[key]. What am I doing wrong?

Starting JSON looks like:

```
[{"word":"hi"},{"word":"howdy"},{"word":"hullo"}]
```

My code:

```
struct Synonym: Codable {
        let word: String
    }
typealias Synonyms = [Synonym]
//Code to create session etc and get data
let mysynonyms = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Synonyms.self, from: data) 

//everything works fine up to here
var words = mysynonyms?[word]! //THROWS ERROR Use of unresolved identifier 'word'
```

Would appreciate any suggestions into why the last line does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`var words = (mysynonyms ?? []).map { $0.word }`

Using the `[]` subscript syntax on a type (struct/class) doesn't work in Swift -- instead, you need to use the dot syntax to get the property. And, since you want all of the words, you can use `map` to transform the array.

I'm also using the `??` to say "if `mysynonyms` is nil, map an empty array instead" so `words` will be `[]` in the event that `mysynonyms` was `nil`.

Comment: Swift 5.2 or later you can use keyPath with map `mysynonyms?.map(\.word) ?? []`

Comment: Thanks, that did the truck.